# Android application connect to local area Wamp Server

Tags: android

I need to connect my app to the wamp server located in my machine within my LAN, in order to test an api I am currently developing. While using the phone internet browser, I can access the ip address for api viewing, but using something similar to the following code does not work.

```
        URL url = new URL("192.168.1.1/api/v1/home");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Please give some suggestions in order to be able to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding http before the link

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.1/api/v1/home");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. this corrected my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the emulator? If so change your IP to this: http://10.0.2.2